# Optimal way to set UIImageView location

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIImageView` that can have 9 possible locations on canvas when ViewDidLoad. Location will be based on

```
var location: Int() or String() (1-9)
```

**Which method would be most optimal, and how to do it?**

1. Have 9 `UIImageView` set in each possible location all 'hidden' and make the appropriate `UIImageView` 'visible' in ViewDidLoad.
2. Have 1 `UIImageView` set in default location 1 and change location based on `location`.

Comment: "Optimal"? What does that _mean_ here? Just _do_ one of them.

Comment: @matt it means 1 of the 2 methods would use up less memory/CPU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number 2. It uses one `UIImageView` and therefore less memory

you can change it's location using  `imageView.frame=CGRectMake(<#CGFloat x#>, <#CGFloat y#>, <#CGFloat width#>, <#CGFloat height#>);`

Comment: what if i want it's location constrained to a particular `UIButton`? ... I'm thinking for auto layout purposes (iPhone to iPad)

Comment: If that's the case then just use the 9 images and hide them, that way you can set the constraints in the interface builder. Otherwise you will have to do it programmatically with logic, changing the constraints based on position. I doubt 9 images will cause any noticeable slowdown anyway, iOS devices push 3d games.

Comment: I don't think this is true. UIImageView takes up no memory. It is the _image_ that takes up memory. And if it is the same image, it is cached, and if it is hidden, the hidden ones don't matter.

Comment: But a hidden one is still an object we have initialised and is therefore in the memory (of course it is almost a negligible amount of memory if there isn't an image in the view). It's 8 hidden UIImageViews and 1 non-hidden versus 1 UIImageView. Obviously we are talking about barely any memory here though.